# Inconsistent ServiceStack exception handling

Tags: servicestack

I have a simple service built with ServiceStack

```
public class GetContactMasterDataService : IService<GetContactMasterData>
{
    public object Execute(GetContactMasterData getContactMasterData)
    {            
        return ContactApi.FetchContactMasterData();
    }
}
```

In a different namespace:

```
public class GetContactMasterData
{

}

public class GetContactMasterDataResponse
{
    public ResponseStatus ResponseStatus { get; set; }
}

public static GetContactMasterDataResponse FetchContactMasterData()
{
    throw new ApplicationException("CRASH");
}
```

When I send a JSON request I correctly get:

```
{
  "ResponseStatus":{
  "ErrorCode":"ApplicationException",
  "Message":"CRASH",
}
}
```

When I send a soap12 request with soapUI, I get the typical yellow screen of death

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>CRASH</title>
...
<h2> <i>CRASH</i> </h2></span>
<b> Description: </b>An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
...
<b> Exception Details: </b>System.ApplicationException: CRASH<br><br>
```

Is this the expected behavior? How can I get a neatly serialized ResponseStatus similar to the JSON response.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry prematurely posted. Updated to include the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML error page you get doesn't looks like it's coming from [ServiceStack](http://www.servicestack.net/), check to see if your website has something that could be hijacking the errors with its own page, e.g: `<customErrors />`.

The correct behavior for SOAP endpoints is to throw a SOAP fault which if you're using either the `Soap11ServiceClient` or `Soap12ServiceClient` [generic service clients](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Clients-overview) will be converted to a `WebServiceException` as seen in this [Integration test](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.WebHost.IntegrationTests/Tests/WebServicesTests.cs#L53):

```
var client = new Soap12ServiceClient(ServiceClientBaseUri);
try
{
    var response = client.Send<AlwaysThrowsResponse>(
        new AlwaysThrows { Value = TestString });

    Assert.Fail("Should throw HTTP errors");
}
catch (WebServiceException webEx)
{
    var response = (AlwaysThrowsResponse) webEx.ResponseDto;
    var expectedError = AlwaysThrowsService.GetErrorMessage(TestString);
    Assert.That(response.ResponseStatus.ErrorCode,
        Is.EqualTo(typeof(NotImplementedException).Name));
    Assert.That(response.ResponseStatus.Message,
        Is.EqualTo(expectedError));
}
```

Comment: Even with <customErrors mode="Off" /> I get the same result. Will try with a different client.